# How to access iPhone Safari History in an App?

Tags: iphone, safari

Is there any way to access History of iPhone Safari?

Regards,
krishnan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the applications are sandboxed and isolated from one another. You can't read data out of one app from another. It's part of the security model.

Would you like some random app to go trolling through your surfing history?

Comment: "Would you like some random app to go trolling through your surfing history?".
No...Obviously nobody likes to loose the privacy, but I really wonder why other Platforms(Other than iOS) allowing the access!!!

Answer (score 1):

Simply put NO, you can't access the Safari History. Apps are sandboxed.

If this is for an in-house app, then you could jailbreak the phones and go around the sandboxing like so -

We can find the history.plist in /var/mobile/Media/Safari/ and this we can read in jailbreaken iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

yes only if you are developing for jailbreak device.