# How to access Safari history from iPhone App using Private Frameworks

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-privateapi

I got a situation something like, i can use **Private Frameworks** of **Apple** in order to  know the operations being performed on **iPhone Safari**( i.e **History** the **Tabs** being browsed and time spend on browsing kind of info).

I have gone through some of the things like Dumping Private frameworks. But i don't know which Framework to Dump i guess WebKit may help. 
Can some body please give the needful info to solve this problem.

i have imported the Dumped classes to Frameworks i.e WebHistory.h, WebHistoryItem.h, WebPreferences.h 
Please let me know in case i miss anything

```
 #import "WebHistory.h"

 - (void)viewDidLoad {

   [super viewDidLoad]; 

   WebHistory *history=[WebHistory optionalSharedHistory];
    NSLog(@"%@",history);

}
```

Comment: Is this for an app destined for the App Store?

Comment: No, In-House App, I duped  but it doesn't work. I fallowed the steps given in URL and but the history is null. i have used WebKit framework. please take a look at updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find the history.plist in /var/mobile/Media/Safari/ and this we can read in jailbreaken iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access the Safari History.  Apps are sandboxed.

If this is for an in-house app, then you might be able to jailbreak the phones and figure out a way around the sandboxing.

Update:

see this SO link:  [how-to-access-iphone-safari-history-in-an-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093703/how-to-access-iphone-safari-history-in-an-app)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need a good web developer who will create the web page in such a way so that you can communicate with javascript and get the message you want to get. And for dumping the framework I think you should get with uikit+ webkit framework.

I hacked my framework by using this link - http://aralbalkan.com/2106 I hope this will help to you .