# Is there a way to access iphone's browser history and app history

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

I dont know whether iam asking a right question..,kindly give your valuable advice.
I want to know:

1. Is it possible to access iPhone's browser history in our code?
2. Is there any way to access app histories (means; which apps i opened recently & what time.)

   waiting for your valuable reply.. Thanks.

Comment: you should accept someone's answer as the response is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your Both Questions.. **No** as Apps are sandboxed in ios.

[How to access iPhone Safari History in an App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093703/how-to-access-iphone-safari-history-in-an-app)
[Getting safari history from phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707757/getting-safari-history-from-phone)
[How to access Safari history from iPhone App using Private Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632792/how-to-access-safari-history-from-iphone-app-using-private-frameworks)

Answer (score 3):

App History can be accessed via a few methods. There are ways using Private APIs, but if you are aiming of the App Store that is probably not a good idea.

[Here](http://forrst.com/posts/UIDevice_Category_For_Processes-h1H) is a UIDevice category to get the Processes currently running on your phone using Public APIs. You have to figure out which app matches which process name, but I have found that it is usually pretty straightforward (e.g. Facebook is Facebook).

Answer (score 1):

We can find the history.plist in **/var/mobile/Media/Safari/** and this we can read in jailbreaken iPhone. And You dont have a way to access app histories either.

Answer (score 1):

There is a History.plist located at /private/var/mobile/Library/Safari for the jailbroken device only.

The history is stored in a property list outside of your applications sandbox and you cannot access it.