# Getting safari history from phone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, safari

I'm creating a custom browser application. 
apart from the sites visited from my browser, i'd like to show the history of the sites visited from safari browser as well.
From my application, can I get the history of the web sites visited from safari browser on iphone or ipod or ipad?

Comment: @srikar You can check how many questions don't even have an answer from anyone ....

Comment: ok, point noted. But please keep in mind that people take time to help others out. Least you could do is contribute reputation to that answers thereby helping the community too. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put **NO**, you can't access the Safari History. Apps are sandboxed.

If this is for an in-house app, then you could jailbreak the phones and go around the sandboxing like so -

We can find the **`history.plist`** in **`/var/mobile/Media/Safari/`** and this we can read in jailbreaken iPhone.

Update:

see this SO link: [How to access iPhone Safari History in an App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093703/how-to-access-iphone-safari-history-in-an-app)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you cannot. The history is stored in a property list outside of your applications **sandbox** and you cannot access it.

On the jailbroken side, there is a **History.plist** located at **`/private/var/mobile/Library/Safari`**

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There is **NO** API to access Safari's browsing history.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Please follow following path then you will retrieve Browser history for iOS7 iPhone.

```
/private/var/mobile/Applications//Library/Safari/History.plist
```

In iOS7 safari app not a system app. When you open Applications folder then you can find history and other plist files.

Comment: Hey Sandeep, I tried this
    NSArray *safariData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"/private/var/mobile/Applications//Library/Safari/History.plist"];

But this returned nil value. Can you please share the code?

Comment: This is always returning null value, did anyone accomplish to do this?