# How can i get the browser history

Tags: iphone

Iam doing one application in iphone.In this i need to get the browsing history of my device.So please tell me how to get the browsing history.If any api is available then please send a like for that.

Comment: Looks like it's unreal. It could be done for uiwebview with js, but not for mobile browser, this may cause privacy issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have access to the history of safari, that is not available to you as a developer

other similar questions [How to access iPhone Safari History in an App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093703/how-to-access-iphone-safari-history-in-an-app)

if you want your own application browsing history please refer to [Getting safari history from phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707757/getting-safari-history-from-phone)